# Fire local notification when dead line is come

Tags: swift, notifications

In my to-do app, I'm trying to set local notification at the time when dead line date for task have been came, but i can't figure out whats wrong with calendar trigger, interval trigger working ok. In function body i put default Date()

```
 func setupNotifications(id: String, contentTitle: String, contentBody: String, date: Date) {
        center.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            if (settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized) {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = contentTitle
                content.body = contentBody
                content.sound = .default
                
                
                let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date().addingTimeInterval(5))
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
                let trigger2 = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                let request2 = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: id, content: content, trigger: trigger2)
                self.center.add(request)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution here
https://github.com/YoussifHany51/ToDoList/blob/main/ToDoList/Models/localNotification.swift
adopted to my project

```
   func setupNotifications(id: String, deadline:Date?) {
    if deadline != nil {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: deadline ?? Date())
        let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: deadline ?? Date())
        let second = calendar.component(.second, from: deadline ?? Date())
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: deadline ?? Date())
        let month = calendar.component(.month, from: deadline ?? Date())
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "To Do"
        content.subtitle = "Today is deadline for: \(id)"
        content.sound = .default
        var operationDate = DateComponents()
        operationDate.hour = hour
        operationDate.minute = minute
        operationDate.second = second
        operationDate.month = month
        operationDate.day = day
        //Trigger
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: operationDate, repeats: false)
        //Request
        let requst = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: id, content: content,trigger: trigger
        )
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(requst)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool!!!! But what I said is still true. :)

Comment: Yes, but i was confused with how to extract data correctly >_<

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
    [.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date().addingTimeInterval(5)
)
```

A time interval is reckoned in seconds. But your `dateComponents` doesn't have any seconds; you've told it to consider only the year, the month, the day, and the hour. And *that* time is in the past.

You can see this simply by converting your date components back to a date:

```
let d = Date()
print(d) // 2022-12-01 14:24:02 +0000
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
    [.year, .month, .day, .hour],
    from: d.addingTimeInterval(5)
)
let d2 = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
print(d2) // 2022-12-01 14:00:00 +0000
```

So at the very least you would need to include `.seconds` in your list of components. That, as you can see, changes everything:

```
import UIKit

let d = Date()
print(d) // 2022-12-01 14:25:22 +0000
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(
    [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .second],
    from: d.addingTimeInterval(5)
)
let d2 = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
print(d2) // 2022-12-01 14:00:27 +0000
```

Comment: I done as you told me, but notification still not showing (

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are _in_ the app five seconds from now, you won't see the notification.

Comment: For test i putting date when i create the task (Current date) and  plus 5 seconds time interval

Comment: So you need to run the code that adds the first `request` and then get out of the app _immediately_ or you won't see the notification.

Comment: No need, i already setup delegate, so notification will appear anyway